# JQuery table rows edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I want to allow the user to click on the link (fa fa-pencil - acts as an edit row link) which is available at the end of each row, (and the rows are entered by the user, therefore have only written HTML code for the headings). When the user clicks on this only that particular row should be made editable to the user 
and then clicking enter on the keyboard should change it back to non editable again. I am unsure how to write the JavaScript for this, my HTML is below

```
<div class = "Data">
                    <div class ="searchBar">
                        <input type = "search" name = "search" id = "search">
                        <a href="#"> <i class = "fa fa-search"></i></a>
                        <button id = "delete">Delete Selected</button>
                    </div>


                <table style ="width:95%" class = "Info">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Select </th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Date of Birth</th>
                        <th><a href ="#"><i class = "fa fa-pencil"></i></a></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
                </div>
```

Please help, would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should find out more about html attribute `contenteditable=true`. So you can do like that: `$('your_th').attr('contenteditable','true');`
Find out more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

Comment: Thanks, I saw this website earlier but I want the user to only be able to edit a row when he clicks on the edit button at the end of the row

Comment: `$('.fa.fa-pencil').on('click', function() {
     //link clicked
})`
It's very basic operation, I won't go any deeper, sorry.